# Why is sleeping inside a critical section a concurrency issue?

Tags: operating-system

I would like to understand why is it a concurrency issue if I try to sleep in a critical section, even though I took a lock.

I could be sleeping because say I'm doing I/O.

Comment: Why would you be sleeping when you are in a critical section?  What are you 'waiting' for?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is basically that while you're sleeping, you're not accomplishing anything. In general, you want to be "in" the critical section for as short of a time as possible. The longer you spend in the critical section, the longer any other thread will have to wait to enter it.

I/O should almost certainly be done outside any critical section as a rule. Just for example, if you're reading some data, you'd want to read the data, then enter the critical section and add the data to some structure so everything else can see it (e.g., add a node with a pointer to that data into a vector), then leave the CS.

There's almost never a good reason to do the I/O itself in a CS -- you'd typically just have a single thread do the I/O, and have a queue (or deque, or whatever) to deal with input to or output from that thread. Adding something to or reading something from the queue is protected by a CS (or perhaps a semaphore, etc.) but happens *quickly* so one thread can do its thing, then quickly get out of the way so other threads can as well.

Comment: There's no reason not to use a "critical section" (poor choice of name for a mutex since it suggests locking code rather than data) for IO if it's just protecting a single IO object. The only threads it will block are others that cannot proceed until they can get a chance to perform IO on it. This is how the internal `FILE` locking works...

Comment: For input, I agree. For output, however, I don't. For output, it's generally adequate to deposit the data in a queue, then continue processing. This can (often drastically) reduce the time the thread spends waiting instead of processing.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of a combined operation like a read-modify-write cycle with an atomicity requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential problem with sleeping during a critical section is that it dramatically increases the probability of a priority inversion scenario.  This can be particularly problematic in real-time systems (as well as non-real-time systems I expect, though perhaps naively I imagine less so).  Although there are various strategies for it, different OSes take different approaches, which will ultimately affect the behaviour of your application.

In the event that you are not familiar with it, consider the following example.

Imagine three (3) tasks of different priority: tLow, tMed and tHigh.  tLow and tHigh will have need a different times to access the same critical resource; tMed does its own thing.

1. tLow is running, tMed and tHigh are presently blocked (but not in critical section).
2. tLow comes along and enters the critical section.
3. tHigh unblocks and since it is the highest priority task in the system, it runs.
4. tHigh then attempts to enter the critical resource but blocks as tLow is in there.
5. tMed unblocks and since it is now the highest priority task in the system, it runs.

tHigh can not run until tLow gives up the resource.  tLow can not run until tMed blocks or ends.  The priority of the tasks has been inverted; tHigh though it has the highest priority is at the bottom of the execution chain.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The concurrency issue with sleeping inside a critical section (also know as a section of code after you lock a semaphore or mutex) is that other processing is much more likely to also block, waiting for your first process to release the critical section.

Blocking other processes isn't always bad. If the other processes have to wait for the first process to finish, then that is the way it is.  So the answer to your questions is that it depends: It might be OK to block other processes if that is the design of your application.

When you are doing I/O your process should be blocked until the I/O completes. Thus it shouldn't need to sleep. But that is another story.